# Passing an array back to the server using JQuery .post()

Tags: jquery, arrays, .post

There are loads of questions and answers regarding the issue of posting arrays back to the server using jquery.

However I cant seem to find any solutiion to the problem I'm having. Basically the code below should return an array of ID's back to the server:

I know the array contains items as the length of the array always matches the number of selects that have the option "true" selected

```
var option = $(".option-select").filter(function () { return $(this).val() == "true"; }).map(function () { return this.id; }).get();
alert(option.length);
$.post("/Quote/GetOptionPrice", { myParam: option }, function (response) { $(".price").html(response); });
```

This is what is passed to the server:

```
"myParam[]"
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: are you remembering to serialize the array before posting it?  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/  <-- that one's the correct url

Answer (score 1):

```
var option = $('.option-select').filter(function () { 
    return $(this).val() == "true"; 
}).map(function () { 
    return this.id; 
}).toArray();

$.ajax({
    url: '/Quote/GetOptionPrice',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { myParam: option },
    traditional: true,
    success: function(response) {
        $('.price').html(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: hi Darin, that still passes "myParam[]" to the server.

Comment: Does setting the `traditional` parameter in the `$.ajax` function make any difference?

Comment: Hi Darin. This passes "myParam" to the server